# combine 3 or more tables, deliberately without a joining condition

Tags: mysql, sql

How do i join **3** or more tables in mysql as follows?

- there is a column for each column of each table (except ID)
- ID field values all go into the same ID field in the new table
- an additional column is added called `table` the values of which is the source Table name
- an autoincremented `newID` field is added
- only one table contributes to each row, unrelated fields have null values
- total number of rows is equal to the sum records from all tables

example with just two tables :

```
TableA:                  TableB          
ID   |   fieldA          ID   |   fieldB 
-----------------       -----------------
  1  |   valueA1           1  |   valueB1
  2  |   valueA2           2  |   valueB2


ResultTable:
newID  | ID  |  table  | fieldA  |  fieldB
---------------------------------------------
   1   |  1  |  TableA | valueA1 |  
   2   |  2  |  TableA | valueA2 |  
   3   |  1  |  TableB |         |  valueB1
   4   |  2  |  TableB |         |  valueB2
```

I know this probably sounds a bit weird!. I am going to try and use this to batch insert nodes for records from various tables into neojs graph database with this [batch-insert](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import) script. which could be hilarious considering I hardly know what I am doing in either database ;-) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Try this one,</strike>

```
SELECT  @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS NewID,
        a.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT  ID, fieldA, '' AS fieldB
        FROM    tableA
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  ID, '' AS fieldA, fieldB
        FROM    tableB
    ) a, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c70ca/2)

- Create New Table

here's the proposed schema

```
CREATE TABLE Newtable
(
    NewID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    FieldA VARCHAR(30),
    FieldB Varchar(30),
    CONSTRAINT tb_pk PRIMARY KEY (NewID)
)
```

- then Insert your values,

here's the query using `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (ID, fieldA, fieldB)
SELECT  ID, fieldA, NULL AS fieldB
FROM    tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT  ID, NULL AS fieldA, fieldB
FROM    tableB
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a table with auto increment newID
2. Add all the possible columns allowing nulls.
3. INSERT INTO it the values from TableA, then TableB with something like:

```
INSERT INTO table
(ID, `table`, fieldA)
SELECT ID, 'TableA', fieldA FROM TableA

INSERT INTO table
(ID, `table`, fieldB)
SELECT ID, 'TableB', fieldB FROM TableB
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION to select all rows in one result set, INSERT INTO for inserting to new table.
Also you can get new ID using ROW_NUMBER() in sql server

```
SELECT ID, COL1, NULL, NULL FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT ID, NULL, COL2, NULL FROM Table2
UNION
SELECT ID, NULL, NULL, COL3 FROM Table3
```

Select above result to a temp table. Use row number to update new ID

```
SELECT ID, ... , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS NewID FROM #TempTable
```